# Etcd service not able to connect k3s

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

I did setup for 3 masters and 5 worker nodes
It was running well previously but now I am seeing a issue related to etcd not able to connect

```
k3s[1510]: {"level":"warn","ts":"2023-06-26T04:33:34.490Z","logger":"etcd-client","caller":"v3@v3.5.3-k3s1/retry_interceptor.go:62","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"etcd-endpoints://0xc000d8a000/127.0.0.1:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded"}
k3s[1510]: time="2023-06-26T04:33:34Z" level=error msg="Failed to check local etcd status for learner management: context deadline exceeded"
k3s[1510]: time="2023-06-26T04:33:34Z" level=info msg="Waiting to retrieve kube-proxy configuration; server is not ready: https://127.0.0.1:6443/v1-k3s/readyz: 500 Internal Server Error"
```

when I try to manually run etcd it starts as expected
but k3s service doesnt start because port 2379 is already in use

Also port 2379 and 2380 are open on all nodes

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error as shown in the provided screenshot while inspecting the logs using the command "journalctl -f -u rke2-server".

[image]

I reviewed the resources of my virtual machine (VM) and discovered that it does not meet the minimum memory requirements.

[image]

The issue was resolved by adjusting the memory using Hyper-V Manager.

[image]

Upon re-evaluating the logs, I no longer observed the error.

[image]

I have successfully restarted the service, and it is currently active.

[image]

Kindly review the allocated resources for your virtual machine (VM) to ensure they meet the minimum requirements.